# How can I build a string by repeating it as many as the number before it?

Tags: javascript

I need code that converts a string into the following form:
`'3[a]2[bc]'`
to the following figure:
`'aaabcbc'`

I have created the following code:

```
function string_builder(expression) {
    let string = expression; //I put the text string into a variable called string.
    let splitString = string.replaceAll('[', ',').replaceAll(']', ',') .split(','); //Replace [and] with , then convert it to an array using that comma.
    let ArrStr = splitString.slice(0,-1); //Delete the last element in the array which is just an empty element. 

    let result = []; //Just empty array inside a variable called result.

    for(let i = 0; i < ArrStr.length; i+=2){ //this loop will take only the numbers by jumping two element every time.
        let num = ArrStr[i]; //variable for numbers.
        let str = ArrStr[i+1]; //variable for stings.
        for(let e = 1; e <= num; e++){ //this loop put every sting in the empty array that called result with the required number.
            result.push(str);
        }
    }

    let finalresult = result.toString().replaceAll(',', ''); //Convert the array (result) to a string and delete the comma between each element.
    return finalresult; //Returns the final result

}
```

But it does not work in the following cases:
'2[abc]3[cd]ef'
'3[a2[c]]'

I'm a beginner, and I've been trying for three days to solve this problem, and I haven't found any suitable idea, any help?

I want this result:

Input: `'2[abc]3[cd]ef'`
Output: `'abcabccdcdcdef'`

Input: `'3[a2[c]]'`
Output: `'accaccacc'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach using the stack data structure to keep track of the nested patterns in the input string. Should work.

```
function decodeString(s) {
  // Create an empty stack to keep track of characters
  const stack = [];
  // Iterate over each character in the input string
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    // If the character is a closing bracket, we need to decode a nested pattern
    if (s[i] === ']') {
      // Create an empty string to store the decoded string inside the nested pattern
      let str = '';
      // Pop characters off the stack until we reach the corresponding opening bracket
      while (stack[stack.length - 1] !== '[') {
        // Concatenate the popped characters to the decoded string
        str = stack.pop() + str;
      }
      // Pop the opening bracket off the stack
      stack.pop();
      // Create an empty string to store the repeat count
      let count = '';
      // Pop characters off the stack until we reach a digit
      while (stack.length > 0 && !isNaN(stack[stack.length - 1])) {
        // Concatenate the popped characters to the repeat count
        count = stack.pop() + count;
      }
      // Convert the repeat count to an integer using parseInt
      count = parseInt(count);
      // Push the repeated decoded string back onto the stack
      stack.push(str.repeat(count));
    } else {
      // If the character is not a closing bracket, push it onto the stack
      stack.push(s[i]);
    }
  }
  // Join the characters remaining on the stack to form the final decoded string
  return stack.join('');
}

// Test the function with the input string "2[abc]3[cd]ef"
const input = "2[abc]3[cd]ef";
const output = decodeString(input); 
console.log(output)  //abcabccdcdcdef
```